# concatenate more than two model of cnn in keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I make model by keras in **CNN like MNIST.h5,cifar10.h5,dogs_and_cats_classification.h5** .but these model is bounded in their own class like mnist only predict handwritten digit or dogs_and_cats_classification.h5 only predict dogs or cats output separately.
but I want to make a **single model**(all.h5) such that that model can predict digit,dogs,cats,or some extra.
so is their any way to do such thing in keras?

please suggest me..
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the last dense layer, add a new dense layer and then retrain your model, or you can create a multi output ensemble, which you can learn more about from keras FAQ.